# Plotly: Markers disappear when (n) points are plotted

Tags: python, python-3.x, plot, plotly, plotly-python

Okay, so my initial idea is to make a line plot in plotly and color the line with one color after certain threshold t, and another color before the threshold. It works for a 23 or less points, but it works with no more, using this method:

```
import numpy as np
import plotly.graph_objects as go

X = [j for j in range(0, 100)]
Y = [j for j in range(100000, 200000, 1000)]
X = X[:23]
Y = Y[:23]
X = np.array(X)
Y = np.array(Y)
t = 4

x = X[X <= t]  # Include the threshold
y = Y[X <= t]
bx = X[X >= t]
by = Y[X >= t]

fig = go.Figure()
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=x, y=y, line=dict(width=4, color='grey'), name="useless data"))
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=bx, y=by, line=dict(width=4, color='blue'), name="useful data"))
fig.update_layout(xaxis_title="x axis", yaxis_title="y axis")
fig.show()
```

So this works normally, and if you run it, you will see that 4 is included in the blue points. But now, please remove the lines where only 23 values are taken (`X = X[:23], Y = Y[:23]`). You will see that 4 is no longer part of the blue points, moreover, the points themselves disappear from the graph in the blue line, you can hover and see data, but you can't see the actual points! If anyone knows why this happens, is it an actual bug or it is normal behaviour and there is something I am missing? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 7):

#### Bug? Not necessarily. Weird behaviour? Perhaps...

In any case, the solution in your case is:

```
fig.data[1].mode = 'lines+markers'
```

---

What you seem to be struggling with here is caused by two things:

1. When hovering over a point where there is one trace represented by a line, and one trace represented by a marker, plotly will display the information for the marker even though the line is placed on top.
2. For an increasing length of a `go.Scatter()` trace, plotly will stop showing markers for after a certain threshold.
3. And this is perhaps the arguably weird part; that the exact threshold does not seem to be determined by the length of the trace alone. We'll take a look at that in the end.

---

#### Details:

---

#### 1. Hover behavior

Just run your code as it is, and hover over `4`:

[image]

Now deselect `useless data` by clicking the name in the legend and you'll get:

[image]

If you zoom in a bit, you'll see that the data is actually there, it just won't show on hover when both traces are activated:

[image]

#### So, what to do about it?

Just include:

```
fig.data[1].mode = 'lines+markers'
```

And get:

[image]

#### 2. Marker trigger threshold for `go.Scatter`

In your case, this threshold seems to be a trace with length = 23 since you're seeing the exact behaviour you're describing. So, what's weird about this? The next part:

#### 3. *Varying* marker trigger threshold

First of all, ***why** is there a threshold? Probably because a trace with too many markers  arguably looks weird:

[image]

You found the threshold to be 24. But in a figure built only with `go.Figure(go.Scatter(x = x, y = y))`, the threshold is 20:

```
pts = 20
x = np.arange(1,pts)
y = np.arange(1,pts)
fig = go.Figure(go.Scatter(x = x, y = y)).show()
```

[image]

```
pts = 21
x = np.arange(1,pts)
y = np.arange(1,pts)
fig = go.Figure(go.Scatter(x = x, y = y)).show()
```

[image]

And I'm not sure ***why***. But I think that would make for a good question on its own.

Comment: Great minds ... seconds apart.  Nice one mate, solid effort and explanation. (+1)

Comment: @S3DEV Likewise!

Comment: Very useful answer! It saved me a lot of time! Thanks to you and S3DEV for helping me! Really appreciated, have a great day!

Answer (score 3):

#### The reason:

This is a 'feature' of Plotly Scatter plots. When (a number) of points are plotted, the underlying Plotly logic converts the 'scatter' plot to a 'line' plot, for rendering efficiency and plot cleanliness. Thus, the *markers* are converted to a solid *line*.

#### The fix:

Simply add `mode='lines+markers'` to the trace.

#### Full working example:

This is your source code, with the minor fix mentioned above:

```
import numpy as np
import plotly.graph_objects as go

X = [j for j in range(0, 100)]
Y = [j for j in range(100000, 200000, 1000)]
#X = X[:23]
#Y = Y[:23]
X = np.array(X)
Y = np.array(Y)
t = 4

x = X[X <= t]  # Include the threshold
y = Y[X <= t]
bx = X[X >= t]
by = Y[X >= t]

fig = go.Figure()
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=x, y=y, mode='lines+markers', line=dict(width=1, color='grey'), name="useless data"))
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=bx, y=by, mode='lines+markers', line=dict(width=1, color='blue'), name="useful data"))
fig.update_layout(xaxis_title="x axis", yaxis_title="y axis")
fig.show()
```

#### Output:

[image]

Comment: Nice one (+1) Beat me by approximately 45 seconds =D

Comment: Very useful answer! It saved me a lot of time! Thanks to you and vestland for helping me! Really appreciated, have a great day! :)

Comment: @Petar - My pleasure. Glad to hear it's been helpful.